# Integrating Twitter bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Basically, I declare my external CSS on my template within the HEAD tag. Then, if I declare another external CSS file (being TB) in the same tag all hell breaks loose in the page. However, all seems OK if I keep the two CSS file declarations away from each other i.e one in body other in head.

Is this a problem doing things this way? Or should I, ideally merge the two CSS files into one great whopping file.

All I want to do is incorporate some elements of TB into an existing layout that I want to keep, as opposed to re-writing everything from scratch.

Thanks.

```
- Sample code :

    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <!-- TemplateBeginEditable name="doctitle" -->
    <title>Test</title>


    <!-- TemplateEndEditable -->
    <!-- TemplateBeginEditable name="head" -->
    <!-- TemplateEndEditable -->

    <!--

    -->

    <link href="../externalsheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <style type="text/css">
    <!--

    -->
    </style>
    </head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../cssverticalmenu.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="../cssverticalmenu.js"></script>

    <body>

    <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="head"><img src="../headtop.jpg" alt="img" width="870" height="153" />
    <div>
    Club test</div>
    </div>

    <div id="content">



     <ul id="verticalmenu" class="glossymenu">
    <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>

    <li><a href="#">Insert and Update</a>
        <ul>
        <li><a href="insertmember.php">Add member into database</a></li>
        <li><a href="insertevent.php">Add event into database</a></li>
        <li><a href="inserttotal.php">Add member total and comment into database</a></li>
        <li><a href="updatemember.php">Update members personal details </a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li><a href="#" >Delete</a>
        <ul>
        <li><a href="deletemember.php">Remove member from database</a></li>
        <li><a href="deleteevent.php">Remove event from database</a></li>
        <li><a href="deltotal.php">Remove member total & comment from database</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" >Show data</a>

    <ul>
        <li><a href="showmember.php">Show members on database</a></li>
        <li><a href="showevent.php">Show events on database</a></li>
        <li><a href="showtotal.php">Show member totals and comments on database</a></li>
        </ul>

    </ul>

      <div class="contentbox"><!-- TemplateBeginEditable name="main box" -->main box<!-- TemplateEndEditable --></div>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.css"> // Attempt here to allow TB to work


    <div id="foot">
        <a href="http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=referer"><img
            src="../Grants.jpg"
            alt="Valid XHTML 1.0 Transitional" width="585" height="80" border="0" /></a>


      <br />
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Couldn't you include the TB CSS file then include your tweaks stylesheet after?  I don't see how those would conflict with one another unless you are using the same class names

Comment: Yes, might be class name conflicts. Any way I have added my template code here. Anything obviously-a-miss?

Comment: If it's a naming conflict (and it probably is), what sort of answer are you looking for?

Comment: I was asking about best practise, and some advice on whether I was doing some that was too apparently wrong. Hope that's OK.

Comment: SO is not really the place for "advice" or "best practices" as they generate opinionated answers/too much discussion.  Try chat or one of the other SE sites next time.  Also, it's best if you start with a valid HTML document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm making a blind guess here, but you may be importing your CSS incorrectly; here's how your CSS should be imported into the `head`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

        <!-- Bootstrap first, then your custom CSS -->
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
        <link href="css/your-css.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Your page content here -->

        <!-- jQuery required for Bootstrap plugins -->
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Perfect, this worked. I think it was perhaps something due to me using type="text/css"..../.